# All solutions that satisfy $ x_{1}^{5}+x_{2}^{5}+x_{3}^{5}+x_{4}^{5}-x_{5}^{5}=0 $

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, procedural-programming

I want to find a combination that satisfies all the solutions of the following formula.
$$
x_{1}^{5}+x_{2}^{5}+x_{3}^{5}+x_{4}^{5}-x_{5}^{5}=0
$$
$x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, $x_{4}$, and $x_{5}$ are integers in the range of 0-300. The code is as follows:

```
Do[If[x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5 - x5^5 == 0, 
  Return[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]], {x1, 300}, {x2, 300}, {x3, 300}, {x4,
   300}, {x5, 300}]
```

The above code is done using a simple loop approach, but too many cycles have resulted in a long time without running a result. Can it satisfy all the solutions of the equation ($x_{1}$-$x_{4}$ size order is not required, only the equation needs to be satisfied in the end) and have a relatively ideal running time.

Comment: Since size order is not required change to `Do[...,{x1,1,300},{x2,x1,300},{x3,x2,300},{x4,x3,300},{x5,x4,300}]` and that will search many MANY fewer and go faster, but 300^5 is still a huge number to check. You might try `FindInstance` and tell it about the increasing size of x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 it sometimes knows tricks to speed up finding solutions, but is still slow.

Comment: You may want to use the famous method of Lander and Parkin (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2003475). Some additional reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture

Comment: If you're patient enough, then `Table[PowersRepresentations[n^5, 4, 5], {n, 0, 300}]` will give you the answer.

Comment: @Roman: I have got a doubt in view of `Table[PowersRepresentations[n^5, 4, 5], {n, 0, 10}]` which results in trivial solutions `{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0, 2}}, {{0, 0, 0, 3}}, {{0, 
   0, 0, 4}}, {{0, 0, 0, 5}}, {{0, 0, 0, 6}}, {{0, 0, 0, 7}}, {{0, 0, 
   0, 8}}, {{0, 0, 0, 9}}, {{0, 0, 0, 10}}}` too.

Comment: If you want to go bigger, you can also find `{5027, 6237, 14068, -220, 14132}` and `{55, 3183, 28969, 85282, 85359}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think Mathematica is suited for this kind of problem. Here's a C code that can solve it in 10 seconds on my laptop:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline uint64_t f(const uint64_t x) { return x * x * x * x * x; }

static void run(const uint64_t s) {
  for (uint64_t x1 = 0; x1 <= s; x1++)
    for (uint64_t x2 = x1; x2 <= s; x2++)
      for (uint64_t x3 = x2; x3 <= s; x3++)
        for (uint64_t x4 = x3; x4 <= s; x4++)
          for (uint64_t x5 = x4; x5 <= s; x5++)
            if (f(x1) + f(x2) + f(x3) + f(x4) == f(x5))
              printf("%" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64
                     "\n",
                     x1, x2, x3, x4, x5);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  uint64_t s;
  if ((argc != 2) || (sscanf(argv[1], "%" PRIu64, &s) != 1)) {
    printf("usage: %s <s>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (s <= 5404) {
    run(s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  } else {
    printf("s=%" PRIu64 " is too large (max: 5404)\n", s);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

Store it as `five.c`, then compile it with

```bash
gcc -O3 five.c -o five
```

and run it with

```bash
./five 300
```

The only non-trivial solutions given are

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 = 27 84 110 133 144
                 54 168 220 266 288
```

(only giving ordered solutions here).

This code can be made much more efficient by replacing the loop over $x_5$ with an integer-fifth-root function. Noticing that the integer fifth powers modulo 11 are all either 0, 1, or 10, we can define

```c
int64_t fifth_root(const uint64_t x) {
  switch (x % 11) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 10: {
    uint64_t y = pow(x, 1. / 5);
    if (f(y) == x)
      return y;
    if (f(y + 1) == x)
      return y + 1;
    return -1;
  }
  default:
    return -1;
  }
}
```

From this, here are the non-trivial solutions up to 1000: (219 seconds)

```
27 84 110 133 144
54 168 220 266 288
81 252 330 399 432
108 336 440 532 576
135 420 550 665 720
162 504 660 798 864
189 588 770 931 1008
```

### comparison with Mathematica's compiler

Code from Mathematica's compiler takes more than a minute:

```
F = Compile[{{s, _Integer}},
  Do[If[x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5 == x5^5,
     Print[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]],
     {x1, 0, s}, {x2, x1, s}, {x3, x2, s}, {x4, x3, s}, {x5, x4, s}],
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

F[300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
... output ...
(*    64.314    *)
```

Looking at `CCodeStringGenerate[F, "compute"]` shows why: the generated C code is very convoluted and the optimizing compiler is probably not able to boil it down to its essence.

`FunctionCompile` is even slower by a factor of 2:

```
G = FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[s, "MachineInteger"],
  Do[If[x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5 == x5^5,
     Print[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]],
     {x1, 0, s}, {x2, x1, s}, {x3, x2, s}, {x4, x3, s}, {x5, x4, s}]]];

G[300] // AbsoluteTiming // First
... output ...
(*    127.053    *)
```

Comment: I would not call all your solutions non-trivial. In fact if you know the first one, then the rest of your solutions are trivial because they are multiplies of the first by `2,3,4,5,6,7`. So the first one is non-trivial and primitive because GCD(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)=1 the rest share common divisor. The next primitive solution is quite bigger.

Comment: @azerbajdzan yes that's right. By "trivial" solutions I meant things like $(0, 0, 0, n, n)$ for any $n$.

Comment: What is your timing for the 300 case?

Comment: @yarchik 11 seconds with the given code; with the `fifth_root()` function it's down to 1.9 seconds.

Comment: Nice, it is an impressive performance, but we do not learn much about Mathematica here.

Comment: @yarchik I agree. But expertise also includes knowing when NOT to use a tool.

Comment: I'm not sure if Mma is suited for this kind of problem. But can't we use `Compile` with `CompilationTarget -> "C"` (or newer `FunctionCompile`) instead of _manually_ writing C code here?

Comment: @user688486 see updates: the comparison is not favorable and hand-written C is still much better.

Comment: @Roman, actually, try writing `x1*x1*x1*x1*x1` (which gets compiled as four multiplications) instead of `x1^5` (which gets compiled to `Power`) in your Mathematica code, the same way you do it in C – I get [_significant_ improvement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENG7a.png) in performance.

Comment: @Domen your example does not count. When you put `Nothing` into the innermost loop, the compiler optimizes the entire loop away (since it does "nothing" and has no side effects). When I keep the `Print` statement in the innermost loop, the gain from `x^5` to `x*x*x*x*x` is only about 13%.

Comment: @Roman, I really think the small performance gain you see is due to a large overhead of `Print` (which has to call the main kernel every time, making compiled code extremely slow). Let me put _something_ in the loop with side effects to [convince you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emsoe.png). Also, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOmhG.png) is a much simpler example of superior performance of multiplication over power.

Answer (score 11):

I am a bit surprised that not a Mathematica solution with a statement "I don't think Mathematica is suited for this kind of problem." is accepted. I do believe that Mathematica is well suited for this kind of problems. As a proof, here is a Mathematica implementation of the Lander and Parkin (1966) [algorithm](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2003475). Notice that it is not even compiled or optimised in any way. Just a  one-to-one implementation of the idea in the article.

```
decomp[2, u_] := Module[{w, v},
  Flatten[
   Reap[Do[Do[
       If[v^5 + w^5 == u, Sow[{v, w}]], {w, Mod[u - v, 30], v, 
        30}], {v, Ceiling[(u/2)^(1/5)], Floor[u^(1/5)]}]] // Last, 1]
  ]

decomp[3, t_, smx_] := Module[{s, l},
  Flatten[
   Reap[Do[l = decomp[2, t - s^5]; 
      Do[Sow[{s, li}], {li, l}], {s, Ceiling[(t/3)^(1/5)], 
       Min[Floor[t^(1/5)], smx]}]] // Last, 1]
  ]

decomp[4, t_] := Module[{s, l},
  Flatten[
   Reap[Do[l = decomp[3, t - s^5, s]; 
      Do[Sow[{s, li}], {li, l}], {s, Ceiling[(t/4)^(1/5)], 
       Floor[t^(1/5)] - 1}]] // Last, 1]
  ]

DeleteCases[Table[decomp[4, i^5], {i, 300}], {}]

(* {{{133, {110, {84, 27}}}}, {{266, {220, {168, 54}}}}} *)
```

Notice that algorithm returns ordered solutions of the form $\{x_4,\{x_3,\{x_2,x_1\}\}\}$, where $x_4\ge x_3\ge x_2 \ge x_1$ and $x_4^5+x_3^5+x_2^5+x_1^5=i^5$.

The time of the run is as follows

```
AbsoluteTiming[DeleteCases[Table[decomp[4, i^5], {i, 300}], {}]]
(*{32.1458, {{{133, {110, {84, 27}}}}, {{266, {220, {168, 54}}}}}}*)
$Version
"13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"
```

Maximal memory used is around 200MB.

Comment: +1. It works even on my weak comp, taking 152.648 s. The second solution is the first one times two.

Comment: Still much slower than C code.

Comment: @azerbajdzan There are many ways to optimise. For instance, `Ceiling[(t/4)^(1/5)]` is computed repeatedly and can be compiled. Also, one can merge all the functions into one.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that an unoptimized c code is faster than (partly) optimized Mathematica code.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, well it's `-O3` unopimized

Comment: @I.M.: What's `-O3`?

Comment: @azerbajdzan, it is a compilation flag used in Roman's answer

Comment: @I.M. Actually, by compiling just some parts of mathematica code I can solve the original problem in 12 seconds, which is just a bit slower than 10 seconds in the Roman's solution. I am sure the timing can be further reduced by skilful optimisation.

Comment: @yarchik, my comment was about C code beeing (in fact) optimized, since compiler flags were used. Perhaps you can try flags too, as far as I remember, compiler flags can be set like `Compiler\`$CCompilerOptions = {"SystemCompileOptions" -> "-O3 -ffast-math -march=native"}`, might have to pre load
`<<CCompilerDriver\``

Answer (score 5):

```
N@GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets[Range[300], 4] // 
  Pick[#, (#^5 . {1,1,1,1})^(1./5) // Unitize[# - Round@#, 1.*^-12] &, 0] & // 
 Round // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {15.7815, {{27, 84, 110, 133}, {54, 168, 220, 266}}}

Note that your computer may need at least 32G RAM.

Comment: A good code is a commented code.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are much better but a brute-force approach by judiciously limiting the potential values of `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4` for a particular value of `x5` is doable.

```
x = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 5}]
x5max = 300;
count = 0;
AbsoluteTiming[
 Do[count = count + 1;
  If[x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5 - x5^5 == 0, Print[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]],
  {x5, x5max},
  {x4, Max[1, Floor[x5/2^(2/5)]], Floor[(x5^5 - 3)^(1/5)]},
  {x3, Max[1, Floor[((x5^5 - x4^5)/3)^(1/5)]], 
    Min[x4, Max[1, Floor[(x5^5 - x4^5)^(1/5)]]]},
  {x2, Max[1, Floor[((x5^5 - x4^5 - x3^5)/2)^(1/5)]], 
    Min[x3, Max[1, Floor[(x5^5 - x4^5 - x3^5)^(1/5)]]]},
  {x1, Max[1, Floor[(x5^5 - x4^5 - x3^5 - x2^5)^(1/5)]],
    Min[x2, Max[1, Ceiling[(x5^5 - x4^5 - x3^5 - x2^5)^(1/5)]]]}]
 ]
(* {27,84,110,133,144} *)
(* {54,168,220,266,288} *)

(* {492.706, Null} *)

count
(* 7512709 *)
```

So about 8 minutes for 7,512,709 combinations examined.

**Edit:**  The comment by @azerbajdzan made me think about reducing the computation time by pre-calculating the 5-th powers of the integers.  I don't know how to speed up or avoid the calculation of the 5-th roots.

```
nmax = 300;
count = 0;
AbsoluteTiming[
 z = Table[i^5, {i, nmax}];
 Do[count = count + 1;
  If[z[[x1]] + z[[x2]] + z[[x3]] + z[[x4]] - z[[x5]] == 0, 
   Print[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]],
  {x5, nmax},
  {x4, Max[1, Floor[x5/2^(2/5)]], Floor[(z[[x5]] - 3)^(1/5)]},
  {x3, Max[1, Floor[((z[[x5]] - z[[x4]])/3)^(1/5)]], 
    Min[x4, Max[1, Floor[(z[[x5]] - z[[x4]])^(1/5)]]]},
  {x2, Max[1, Floor[((z[[x5]] - z[[x4]] - z[[x3]])/2)^(1/5)]], 
    Min[x3, Max[1, Floor[(z[[x5]] - z[[x4]] - z[[x3]])^(1/5)]]]},
  {x1, Max[1, Floor[(z[[x5]] - z[[x4]] - z[[x3]] - z[[x2]])^(1/5)]],
    Min[x2, Max[1, Ceiling[(z[[x5]] - z[[x4]] - z[[x3]] - z[[x2]])^(1/5)]]]}]
 ]
(* {27,84,110,133,144} *)
(* {54,168,220,266,288} *)

(* {401.692261`,Null} *)

count
(* 7512709 *)
```

Pre-computing the 5-th powers saves about 90 seconds.

Comment: Doesn't lots of computation of fifth's roots slow down the code instead?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thanks for that.  I've incorporated part of your suggestion but I don't know how to speed up the calculation of the 5-th roots.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can compare speed of identical codes in Mathematica with `For` loop or `Do` loop with Python code executed from Mathematica.

```
n = 134;
er = 10^-10;
For[x1 = 1, x1 <= n, x1++,
 For[x2 = x1, x2 <= n, x2++,
  For[x3 = x2, x3 <= n, x3++,
   For[x4 = x3, x4 <= n, x4++,
    yp = x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5;
    ypm = Mod[yp, 11];
    If[ypm == 0 || ypm == 1 || ypm == 10, y = yp^(1/5.); 
     If[Mod[y, 1] < er, Print[{x1, x2, x3, x4}]]]]]]]
```

---

```
n = 134;
er = 10^-10;
Do[yp = x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5;
 ypm = Mod[yp, 11];
 If[ypm == 0 || ypm == 1 || ypm == 10, y = yp^(1/5.); 
  If[Mod[y, 1] < er, Print[{x1, x2, x3, x4}]]], {x1, 1, n}, {x2, x1, 
  n}, {x3, x2, n}, {x4, x3, n}]
```

---

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "print()
n=134
er=10**(-10)
for x1 in range(1,n):
  for x2 in range(x1,n):
    for x3 in range(x2,n):
      for x4 in range(x3,n):
        yp=x1**5+x2**5+x3**5+x4**5
        ypm=yp%11
        if ypm==0 or ypm==1 or ypm==10:
          y=yp**(1/5)
          if y%1<er:
            print([x1,x2,x3,x4])"]
```

[image]

---

```
print()
n=134
er=10**(-10)
for x1 in range(1,n):
  for x2 in range(x1,n):
    for x3 in range(x2,n):
      for x4 in range(x3,n):
        yp=x1**5+x2**5+x3**5+x4**5
        ypm=yp%11
        if ypm==0 or ypm==1 or ypm==10:
          y=yp**(1/5)
          if y%1<er:
            print([x1,x2,x3,x4])
```

`AbsoluteTiming` for each method with `n=134`:

`Mathematica For`: 83 seconds

`Mathematica Do`: 74 seconds

`Python For`: 23 seconds

Comment: `Block[{n=133+1,y5},(*Parallel*)Do[Switch[Mod[y5=x1^5+x2^5+x3^5+x4^5,11],0|1|10,If[FractionalPart[y5^0.2]<1*^-10,PrintTemporary[{x1,x2,x3,x4}]]],{x1,n},{x2,x1,n},{x3,x2,n},{x4,x3,n}]]` is more compact and, in effect, more efficient.  
Now that these expressions are parallelizable, what about replacing Python's built-in `for` with its parallel form (e.g., [parfor](https://github.com/wimpomp/parfor))?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Here is an elementary (but long) way to do it.
First, in view of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) each solution of `x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5 - x5^5 == 0` in positive integers is a solution of `Mod[a + b + c + d - e, 5] == 0` with `a==x1^5` and so on. First, we do

```
res = Solve[ Mod[a + b + c + d - e, 5] == 0 && {a, b, c, d, e} >= 
1 && {a, b, c, d, e} <= 5, {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers];
```

Now we select the solution with `e==1`(125 items)

```
Map[#[[1 ;; 4]] &, {a, b, c, d, e} /. Select[res, #[[5]][[2]] == 1 &]]
```

In fact, many of those are the same (think of permutations of the first four variables), so in order to delete duplicates

```
DeleteDuplicates[%, SymmetricDifference[#1, #2] == {} &]
```

> `{{1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 4,  4}, {1, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 5, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 5}, {2, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3,  3, 3}, {2, 4, 5, 5}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 5}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}`

Now we switch to `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5`. For example (My comp is weak.),

```
Do[If[x1^5 + x2^5 + x3^5 + x4^5 - x5^5 == 0,  Return[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]], {x1, 1, 150, 5},  
{x2, 1, 150,5}, {x3, 1, 150, 5}, {x4, 3, 150, 5}, {x5, 1, 150, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{110.114, Null}`

All the cases can be considered in a couple of hours.

Comment: What is incorrect in the above?